# Linking head and tail in a self-implemented queue C++

Tags: c++, queue

Doing a self-impl queue in C++. The question is about adding the first element. I know there's an obvious way of ckecking if head is NULL then we also change head, if no then we don't touch it. But I was told there's another way which I didn't understand. The example was like this:

```
first = (QueueNode*)&last;
```

then I should assign last element and no if-check required. But it actually doesn't work, so is there a way to implement what I'm talking about and what did I get wrong?

```
struct QueueNode
{
    T data;
    QueueNode* next;
} *first, *last;
```

edit:
The usual way we implement Enqueue operation is

```
void Enqueue(T data)
{
    QueueNode* node = new QueueNode();
    node->data = data;
    node->next = last;
    last = node;
    if (first == NULL) first = last; // <- THIS is what I want to get rid off
}
```

Comment: What are the types of first and last?

Comment: Edited the q to show the struct of first and last

Comment: I think think the "another way which I didn't understand" was implemented incorrectly.  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Does the "another way" entail initializing the first and last pointers to point to a dummy (non-data) head node when constructing the queue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
first = (QueueNode*)&last;
```

where :

```
struct QueueNode
{
    T data;
    QueueNode* next;
} *first, *last;
```

you already declare `last` **as pointer**, then when you assign it to `first` you dereference  again this pointer.

**So you have a pointer to pointer to the `QueueNode` struct.**